# Query to check whether a column is nullable with Entity Framework and C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, nullable

To determine in SQL if a column can have null values I do the following:

```js
SELECT IS_NULLABLE 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' 
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
  AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'
```

In C# and with Entity Framework, I'm doing the following:

```js
var varx = context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("select IS_NULLABLE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'AND COLUMN_NAME = 'column_name'");
```

But `varx` is always -1 regardless of whether or not the column accepts null values.

Any comments or suggestions are welcome

Comment: ExecuteSqlCommand only returns the number of rows affected, it isn't used for querying data, which is why you're getting -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things you can try to solve your issue -

Use EF `SqlQuery` instead of `ExecuteSqlCommand` as -

```
string studentName = ctx.Database.SqlQuery<string>("Select studentname from Student where studentid=@id", new SqlParameter("@id", 1))
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Note that Database.`ExecuteSqlCommnad()` method is useful in executing database commands, such as the Insert, Update and Delete command.

**Also**

I suggest you **edit your SQL** to use `SYS.COLUMNS` table as shown below.
`dbo.Worker` is my database table with `Worker_Id` as Not Null column and `First_Name` as Nullable column

```
SELECT IS_NULLABLE FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Worker') AND NAME = 'Worker_id' --Returns 0  

SELECT IS_NULLABLE FROM SYS.COLUMNS 
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('dbo.Worker') AND NAME = 'First_Name' --Returns 1
```

SYS.COLUMNS is a system table and is used for maintaining information on columns in a database. For every column added in a database, a record is created in the SYS.COLUMNS table.

Comment: In general I wouldn't recommend someone to use a sys.* table over an information_schema.* view, the latter is ISO standard, the former is more likely to differ from one vendor to the next. In this case you'll probably find that information_schema is backed by the sys.* tables.

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, if you're using EF6 [SqlQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/raw-sql) can execute a query and return a result.

However it is possible to get this information out of EF6 without doing a query if you're prepared to get your hands dirty and interrogate EF itself. Lets face it, EF needs to know this sort of thing to do its job, right?

Firstly, credit to [romiller](https://romiller.com/2015/08/05/ef6-1-get-mapping-between-properties-and-columns/) for the guts of this.

The following is a modification of a method that I've used to get similar info for entity auditing. It works out the corresponding storage property for the specified model property to, in this case, return whether the column is nullable or not.

```
public static class DbContextExtensions
{
    public static bool IsPropertyNullableFor(this DbContext context, Type type, string propertyName)
    {
        var metadataWorkspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;

        var objectItemCollection = (ObjectItemCollection) metadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace.OSpace);

        var entityType = metadataWorkspace
            .GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace)
            .Single(e => objectItemCollection.GetClrType(e) == type);

        var entitySet = metadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityContainer>(DataSpace.CSpace)
            .Single()
            .EntitySets
            .Single(s => s.ElementType.Name == entityType.Name);

        var entitySetMapping = metadataWorkspace
            .GetItems<EntityContainerMapping>(DataSpace.CSSpace)
            .Single()
            .EntitySetMappings
            .Single(s => s.EntitySet.Equals(entitySet));

        var column = entitySetMapping
            .EntityTypeMappings.Single()
            .Fragments.Single()
            .PropertyMappings
            .OfType<ScalarPropertyMapping>()
            .Single(m => m.Property.Name == propertyName)
            .Column;

        return column.Nullable;
    }
}
```

Invoked like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Is id nullable?: " + dbContext.IsPropertyNullableFor(typeof(MyClass), nameof(MyClass.Id)));
```

You could tighten up the interface with generics/expressions, this is just a demonstration of how to do it.